# Incorrect syntax near '='.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display my data on my website, using asp.net and c# but im getting this error, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='. please help, i have double check my code but nothing seems to be wrong.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RDCINFOS"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    string str;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand("select * from articles where id=" + Request.Params["x"], con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.Open();
        dr= cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            art.InnerHtml +=  "<br>" + dr["title"] + "</br><br>";
            art.InnerHtml +=  dr["details"] + "<br>";
            art.InnerHtml +=  "<img src=pict/" + dr["photo"] + " height=300 width=200/><br>";
        }

    }
```

Comment: This will solve the issue : `id='" + Request.Params["x"] + "'"`

Comment: Any chance the value of Request.Params["x"] is empty or null?

Comment: What line exactly is the exception?

Comment: Thanks you so much  @un-lucky, you make my day, it works.

Comment: Don't build SQL queries using string concatenation. You now have an SQL Injection vulnerability in your application. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Don't build queries by concatenating strings. Look into *parameterized queries*. At the moment, your code is practically a textbook example of an SQL Injection vulnerability (I.e. work out what happens when the request parameter X is set to `'; drop table articles; --`).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it will throw exception `Incorrect syntax near '='` :D but this one `5;drop table articles;` could do something ;)

Comment: your code mixes SQL with presentation; uses direct user input in SQL (what @Damien_The_Unbeliever said); uses direct ConfigurationManager calls instead of using the wrapper visual studio generates. You should learn coding from a good book before trying to write some.

Comment: @Sergio - my injection was based on larie apparently accepting un-lucky's suggestion. Or any of the answers. Not the original "broken" code - the *new* broken code.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, check if `Request.Params["x"]` is not null, and then change

```
SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand("select * from articles where id=" + Request.Params["x"], con);
```

to

```
SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand("select * from articles where id=@id", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Request.Params["x"]);
```

Comment: Proper solution that fixes the problem AND removes the SQL Injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.Params["x"]` possible `empty`, `null` or `other type` than id column in database

Comment: Yep, there may be possibilities, but does it throw syntax errors?

Comment: @un-lucky, your first answer solve my problem. thank you

Comment: @un-lucky, your first answer solve my problem thank you

Comment: @larie: its ok buddy, but you should consider `CodeCaster's` comment as well parameterization will be the right option

Comment: @un-lucky yes, if type `int` in database, and you try to pass `string` value